# NullPointerException when binding the service in the OnCreate() method

Tags: java, android, service

I want to bind a service to an activity in order to read from the service some data retrieved from the phone and display it in a TextView.

Please refer to the code below: `Facts()` method will use the `mService` reference that should not be null after calling the `StartServiceFacts` Method , but it is null.

However when I'm calling `tFacts.setText(Onfacts)` method in a separate button it works OK. So why I can't bind to the service in the `onCreate` method and how can I achieve that in order to avoid using any additional button?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.handsetdetailsactivity);
    mConnection = new ConnectionClass();
    tFacts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tHandsetDtails);
    Intent intent = new Intent(HandsetDetailsActivity.this, 
        ServiceDeviceFacts.class);
    startService(intent);
    StartServiceFacts();
    tFacts.setText(Facts());
}

void StartServiceFacts() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceDeviceFacts.class);
    try {
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Exception in the service", ex.toString());
    }
    Log.e("mBound value", mBound + "");
}

private class ConnectionClass implements ServiceConnection {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        ServiceBinder binder = (ServiceBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};
```

Log cat message error :

```
10-07 11:41:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(24964): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 11:41:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(24964): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testma/com.testma.activities.HandsetDetailsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-07 11:41:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(24964):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
10-07 11:41:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(24964):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
10-07 11:41:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(24964):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-07 11:41:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(24964):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
10-07 11:41:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(24964):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-07 11:41:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(24964):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-07 11:41:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(24964):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
10-07 11:41:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(24964):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 11:41:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(24964):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-07 11:41:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(24964):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
10-07 11:41:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(24964):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
10-07 11:41:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(24964):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-07 11:41:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(24964): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-07 11:41:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(24964):    at com.testma.activities.HandsetDetailsActivity.Facts(HandsetDetailsActivity.java:81)
10-07 11:41:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(24964):    at com.testma.activities.HandsetDetailsActivity.onCreate(HandsetDetailsActivity.java:36)
10-07 11:41:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(24964):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-07 11:41:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(24964):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
10-07 11:41:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(24964):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post your log cat error..

Comment: @Tamilan : I have updated the message with the log cat error . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding to a `Service` is an `Asynchronous` operation. That is why you cannot perform service oriented operations right after calling `StartServiceFacts()`.

You have to wait till **onServiceConnected** method is called in `ConnectionClass`, which confirms its bind with the `Activity`.

Regarding your button mystery! The reason why it works fine in button-press is because the service has already been bind before the **onClick** of your button is raised.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Waqas . So have you any idea how can I perform the binding in the activity creation without using this button ?

Comment: whatever related to your Service you are calling in onClick of your button, call it in `onServiceConnected` and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm when moving the teatement to the OnServiceConnected method .